# Flutter radio button on change is not updating Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, radio-button

I'm new to flutter, I'm trying to do a CRUD and I have a problem. On my update screen I can send all fields on my form to Firebase Firestore except radio fields. This problem only happens in the update, because in the create the radios are working well. I can't see where I'm going wrong in the update, could you help me?

The code bellow is my class

```
class _DetailFormState extends State<DetailForm> {
  final DataRepository repository = DataRepository();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  String sex;

  @override
  void initState() {       
    sex = widget.user.sex;
    super.initState();
  }
```

These are my radio buttons:

```
      ListTile(
        title: Align(
          child: new Text("Female"),
          alignment: Alignment(-1.2, 0),
        ),
        leading: Radio(
          value: "female",
          groupValue: widget.user.sex,
          onChanged: (String value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.user.sex = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Align(
          child: new Text("Male"),
          alignment: Alignment(-1.2, 0),
        ),
        leading: Radio(
          value: "male",
          groupValue: widget.user.sex,
          onChanged: (String value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.user.sex = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
```

This is where I call my Firebase repository to save the data. As I said earlier, I can save any field except radio. This is my problem. No error message appears. The data is simply not updated in Firebase

```
  Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade600,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Cancel",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                      )),
    MaterialButton(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade600,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();                   
                        widget.user.sex = sex;
                        repository.updateUser(widget.user);  

                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Update",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
```

Edit 1

```
  updateUser(User user) async {
    await collection
        .document(user.reference.documentID)
        .updateData(user.toJson());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was putting the value of the widget to receive the value of the variable that was already in Firebase:

```
onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();                   
                        widget.user.sex = sex;
                        repository.updateUser(widget.user);  

                      }
```

In fact, the opposite should be done. The variable that is in Firebase receives the value that is in the widget:

```
onPressed: () async {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();                   
                            sex = widget.user.sex;
                            repository.updateUser(widget.user);  

                          }
```